SparkNLP DocumentAssembler raises TypeError :'JavaPackage' object is not callable
Its my first time using spark and I am encountering some problems when I try to initiate DocumentAssembler. I am using Anaconda Jupyter. Really appreciate any help I can get! :)
I ran the following code:
spark = sparknlp.start()

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark NLP") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "16G") \
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M") \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.12:5.3.3") \
    .getOrCreate()

source_text_assembler = DocumentAssembler() \
    .setInputCol('source_text') \
    .setOutputCol('source_text_document') \
    .setIdCol('aid') \
    .setCleanupMode('inplace_full')

source_test_docs = source_text_assembler.transform(spark_df)
source_test_docs.limit(5).toPandas()

And this error was raised:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In\[26\], line 3 1 from sparknlp.base import DocumentAssembler \----\> 3 source_text_assembler = DocumentAssembler() \ 4     .setInputCol('source_text') \ 5     .setOutputCol('source_text_document') \ 6     .setIdCol('aid') \ 7     .setCleanupMode('inplace_full') 9 source_test_docs = source_text_assembler.transform(spark_df) 10 source_test_docs.limit(5).toPandas()

File \~\\spark\\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\\python\\pyspark\__init_\_.py:139, in keyword_only.\<locals\>.wrapper(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs) 137     raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__) 138 self.\_input_kwargs = kwargs \--\> 139 return func(self, \*\*kwargs)

File \~.conda\\Lib\\site-packages\\sparknlp\\base\\document_assembler.py:96, in DocumentAssembler.__init__(self) 94 @keyword_only 95 def __init__(self): \---\> 96     super(DocumentAssembler, self).__init__(classname="com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.DocumentAssembler") 97     self.\_setDefault(outputCol="document", cleanupMode='disabled')

File \~\\spark\\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\\python\\pyspark\__init_\_.py:139, in keyword_only.\<locals\>.wrapper(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs) 137     raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__) 138 self.\_input_kwargs = kwargs \--\> 139 return func(self, \*\*kwargs)

File \~.conda\\Lib\\site-packages\\sparknlp\\internal\\annotator_transformer.py:36, in AnnotatorTransformer.__init__(self, classname) 34 self.setParams(\*\*kwargs) 35 self.__class__.\_java_class_name = classname \---\> 36 self.\_java_obj = self.\_new_java_obj(classname, self.uid)

File \~\\spark\\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\\python\\pyspark\\ml\\wrapper.py:86, in JavaWrapper.\_new_java_obj(java_class, \*args) 84     java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name) 85 java_args = \[\_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args\] \---\> 86 return java_obj(\*java_args)

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable 

In an attempt to troubleshoot based on what I read online, I printed the following but was still unsure where the issue lies:
print(sys.path)

['C:\Users\USER', 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-263962a5-0df8-4d47-9471-1d46e5918635\userFiles-c3a490d4-e01c-4b35-a6ce-bf6508b3153f', 'C:\Users\USER\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip', 'C:\Users\USER\spark\spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3\python', 'C:\Users\USER', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\python311.zip', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\DLLs', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\Lib', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda', '', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\Lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\Lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\USER\.conda\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

pip show sparknlp

Name: sparknlp
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: John Snow Labs Spark NLP is a natural language processing library built on top of Apache Spark ML. It provides simple, performant & accurate NLP annotations for machine learning pipelines, that scale easily in a distributed environment.
Home-page: http://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com
Author: John Snow Labs
Author-email:
License: UNKNOWN
Location: C:\Users\USER.conda\Lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, spark-nlp
Required-by:
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

print("Spark NLP version")
print(sparknlp.version())
print("Apache Spark version")
print(spark.version)


Spark NLP version
5.3.3
Apache Spark version
3.5.1

